# Display null values for non existing row data in postgres DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below Dataset which looks like this.

```
t               mean        max     min     std     data_id
4/14/2010 0:00  12.6941 12.6941 12.6941 12.6941          1
4/14/2010 0:00  12.3851 12.3851 12.3851 12.3851          2
4/14/2010 0:20  12.389  12.389  12.389  12.389           1
4/14/2010 0:20  12.1836 12.1836 12.1836 12.1836          2
4/14/2010 0:20  11.3887 11.3887 11.3887 11.3887          6
```

Here the unique data_id are(1,2,6) but i have another data_id set (1,2,4,5,6) which i want to use to get the data.

Now for all the data_id not present for the time t i want to add the null (mean,max.std,min) values to them so in this case i want the below result set:-

```
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
'2010-04-14 00:20:00','12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,,,,,,,,,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887'
```

I have used the below query:-

```
with dataset as (
      select *
      from (values ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 1),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 2),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 1),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 2),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 6)
           ) AS data(t, mean, max, min, std, data_id)
      ),
     dataset_full as (
       select t.t, d.data_id,
              ds.mean, ds.max, ds.min, ds.std
       from (select distinct t from dataset) t cross join
            (select distinct data_id from dataset) d left join
            dataset ds
            on ds.t = t.t and ds.data_id = d.data_id
     )
select t,string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',' order by data_id)
from dataset_full
group by t
order by t;
```

And i am getting the below result:-

```
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,,,,'
    '2010-04-14 00:20:00','12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887'
```

I am not getting the null values for data_id (4,5,6) at = 4/14/2010 0:00 and data_id (4,5) at t=4/14/2010 0:20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the ids that you want when you define `data_set_full`:

```
dataset_full as (
       select t.t, d.data_id,
              ds.mean, ds.max, ds.min, ds.std
       from (select distinct t from dataset) t cross join
            (values (1), (2), (4), (5), (6)) d(data_id) left join
            dataset ds
            on ds.t = t.t and ds.data_id = d.data_id
     )
```

The purpose of the `cross join` is to get all the records that you want in the result set.  So, include the ids and the timestamps that you want.  The `left join` then brings in the appropriate data, if any.